# Trying to have css specifically for a page loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, dom

I'm trying to have it so the CSS for the AJAX loaded page is only within the page (so it's on it's own as opposed to one large css file). It would look something like this

```
$("#content").load(pageid+".html #content > *", function etc...
```

and the content that would be loading into the page would look like...

```
<div id="content">
    <style>
        body{
            background-color:blue;
        }
    </style>
    content here
</div>
```

edit: The question is, how can I get that style to be applied, as it's currently not.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The HTML you are trying to load is invalid. It probably gets error corrected before jQuery extracts the bit you care about. Don't write invalid HTML.

Comment: @Quentin im confused as to why the HTML is invalid. In HTML5, style can be scoped within the body.

Comment: @Stewartside — No. In earlier drafts of HTML 5 it could be, but (a) that markup is not since it requires a specific attribute (b) you need browser support for it (which is lacking) and (c) it was removed before HTML 5 was published (mostly due to the lack of b).

Answer (score 0):

The CSS declaration that you inject into the DOM after the AJAX request has been completed doesn't modify the background color of the body because it doesn't reload the page. If you want to change the background color after the request without reloading the page, you should probably use JavaScript. Like so:

`document.getElementById("elementId").style.backgroundColor = "blue";`

Hope it helps.